# Reading ε using python

Tags: python

So I am trying to read the following line from the source file called 'bad_grammar_4.txt':

```
B -> ε
A -> ε
```

The code I used read in the above file, and i tried to print it out , but it produces the following output

```
A -> Îµ
B -> Îµ
```

Since I want to use my code to do something whenever there is a ε in the line.
But I couldn't figure out what should I use in my if statement in order to capture the existence of ε. It seems like python just doesn't recognise ε at all....

Can anyone show me how should ε be recognised ?

This is the Code i used to print the file out directly:

```
with open('bad_grammar_4.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a string contains a substring like:

```
>>> 'o' in 'hello'
True
>>> 'el' in 'hello'
True
>>> 'x' in 'hello'
False
>>> 'hex' in 'hello'
False
```

You can find how Python encode a character like:

```
>>> 'ε'
'\xce\xb5'
>>> 'π'
'\xcf\x80'
>>> 'ρ'
'\xcf\x81'
```

So, we know `ε` is encoded as `\xce\xb5`. Then you can basically:

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if '\xce\xb5' in line:
          print(line)
```

Comment: That doesn't really explain how to read the line to get `ε`, does it?

Comment: Thanks, It does help me recognise ε now.

Answer (score 2):

The encoding of the file has been guessed incorrectly:

```
with open('bad_grammar_4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
   ...
```

Or with Python 2.x:

```
with io.open('bad_grammar_4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
   ...
```

Comment: Decoding the file properly and doing the match with Unicode is a much better idea than searching for the encoded string in encoded text.